# Id is not getting on url of ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I am working on categories and its subcategories when in my code I am getting id from category but it is not able to pass into Ajax and its URL.
My code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">


    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('select[name="category"]').on('change', function() {
            var stateID = $(this).val();
            if(stateID) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: "<?php echo base_url("myformAjax");?>/"+stateID,
//                    alert(url);
                    type: "GET",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success:function(data) {
                        $('select[name="subcategory"]').empty();
                        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                            $('select[name="subcategory"]').append('<option value="'+ value.id +'">'+ value.subcategory +'</option>');
                        });
                    }
                });
            }else{
                $('select[name="subcategory"]').empty();
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: can you alert this `alert("<?php echo base_url("myformAjax");?>/"+stated)`?

Comment: Show us the PHP code in `myformAjax`

Comment: are you getting `stateID`? where is `controller/method` format in url? Please add that format in single quote

Comment: thanks i am getting stateID before   if(stateID) {   and not getting values of alert("<?php echo base_url("myformAjax");?>/"+stated)

Answer (score 0):

you have a mistake in your code.

you are using double-quotes inside double-quotes

change this line

```
 url: "<?php echo base_url("myformAjax");?>/"+stateID,
```

to

```
 url: "<?php echo base_url('myformAjax');?>/"+stateID,
```

**updated answer:**

assign the php value to js variable and concat both.

```
var phpVal = <?php echo base_url('myformAjax');?>;
```

and then

```
url: phpVal + "/" + stateID,
```